# Ubuntu Server hardware error

Tags: server, hardware

My PC recently had some stability issues. I ran memtest86 and found a bad RAM stick. I took the stick out, but the issues weren't gone. I installed Ubuntu Server to check for problems, and immediately after the installation, this error message appeared. What does it mean? Is my CPU broken?

[image: Picture of the Error]

Comment: If the error didn't stop, you removed the wrong RAM stick.

Comment: i ran memtest86 again with the three remaining sticks and got 0 Errors after round about 24 hours of runtime.

Comment: It could also be a damaged CPU cache ... in this case, yes, your CPU is effectively broken.

Comment: I believe that the errors indicate that your ram detected and corrected an error using its built in ECC.  It isn't a good sign, but at least it fixed the problem, which also would be why memtest thought it was ok.